# Magento 1.x : Custom emails sent by cronjob returning admin store url instead of store base url

Tags: email, multistore, email-templates, stores

Here is how I'm sending emails from my multi-site magento 1.9.2.4, this function is called by a cron job & working fine to send emails.

Everything is working fine but all of the emails templates (there are different templates for different wesbsites/stores) have store url of admin. I don't know why `{{store url=""}}"` & `"{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}` are returning admin store url instead of the Store Id I'm setting to template

```
public function sendEmail($templateId, $vars,$storeId ,$name, $email)
{
    try {

        $from_email     = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email',$storeId); //fetch sender email Admin
        $from_name      = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name',$storeId); //fetch sender name Admin
        $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
        $emailTemplate->setStoreId($storeId);
        $emailTemplate->load($templateId);

        $emailTemplate->setSenderName($from_name);
        $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($from_email);

        foreach ($vars as $key => $value) {
            $emailtemplateVariables[$key]  = $value;
        }

        $result = $emailTemplate->send($email, $name, $emailtemplateVariables);

        Mage::log("Template Id : ".$templateId." send result : ".$result,null,"T-Emails.log");

    } catch(Exception $ex) {
        Mage::log($ex->getMessage(), null,"T-Emails.log");
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: set the template design config `$emailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $storeId));`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for you question :) Maybe it'll be useful for someone.

In your Cron method you have to add

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($storeId);
```

I hope I can help someone :)